# localinstall from cdrom can't find dependencies - RHEL 6.2

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, dependencies

I have `.iso` of RHEL 6.2 with basic packages inside. When I install a rpm using `yum install` or `yum localinstall` it can't install due to  it can't find the dependencies although it can be found inside the packages folder.

```
[root@DEVSI Packages]# yum localinstall libstdc++-*
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686.rpm: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686
Marking libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686.rpm to be installed
Examining libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64.rpm: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Examining libstdc++-devel-4.4.6-3.el6.i686.rpm: libstdc++-devel-4.4.6-3.el6.i68
Marking libstdc++-devel-4.4.6-3.el6.i686.rpm to be installed
Examining libstdc++-devel-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64.rpm: libstdc++-devel-4.4.6-3.el6.x6_64
libstdc++-devel-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64.rpm: does not update installed package.
Examining libstdc++-docs-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64.rpm: libstdc++-docs-4.4.6-3.el6.x8664
Marking libstdc++-docs-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libstdc++.i686 0:4.4.6-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ld-linux.so.2 for package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i68
--> Processing Dependency: ld-linux.so.2(GLIBC_2.3) for package: libstdc++-4.4.-3.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6 for package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) for package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.l6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) for package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.l6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) for package: libstdc++-4.4.6-.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) for package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.l6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) for package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.l6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2) for package: libstdc++-4.4.6-.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) for package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.l6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6 for package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) for package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.l6.i686
---> Package libstdc++-devel.i686 0:4.4.6-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libstdc++-docs.x86_64 0:4.4.6-3.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 (/libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0)
Error: Package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 (/libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1)
Error: Package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 (/libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686)
           Requires: ld-linux.so.2(GLIBC_2.3)
Error: Package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 (/libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)
Error: Package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 (/libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686)
           Requires: libm.so.6
Error: Package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 (/libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.0)
Error: Package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 (/libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)
Error: Package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 (/libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686)
           Requires: libc.so.6
Error: Package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 (/libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)
Error: Package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 (/libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2)
Error: Package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 (/libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686)
           Requires: ld-linux.so.2
Error: Package: libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686 (/libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the output of `yum repolist`? Sounds like it just needs a repository configured.

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along  - `yum repolist
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
repolist: 0`

Comment: what is the mountpoint of the .iso? EDIT: nvm just re-read the title. On it.

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along - Do you mean filesystem : `/dev/sr0` mounted on `/mnt/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to configure the repository so Yum knows where to find the packages. There's a few steps involved so bear with me.

**Make a new mountpoint for the iso and mount it there**

Note: as you stated in your title that this is on a CDROM, the path in the mount command below will be the path to the CDROM and the iso on it.

```
mkdir /isomount
mount -o loop /path/to/.iso /isomount
```

**Get the ID**

This is important for the next step.

```
head -n1 isomount/.discinfo
```

**Create a new .repo file**

Make a new file, `/etc/yum.repos.d/new.repo` and add the following (mediaid is the ID you retrieved in the last step):

```
[repository] 
mediaid=<media_id> 
name=Disk Repository
baseurl=file:///isomount/path/to/repo
enabled=1 
gpgcheck=0
```

You may need to use `gpgcheck=1` with `gpgkey=` but try it without beforehand.

**Finally**

Update Yum to make the changes take effect.

```
yum update
```

Answer (score 1):

`yum` needs a *repository file* to tell it which repositories to use, and where they are.  Your ISO has packages, but that's not enough.

`yum` looks in `/etc/yum.repos.d` for the repository files.  You can make one, as detailed in *[Install from DVD using YUM installer](http://fedora-help.blogspot.com/2009/07/install-from-dvd-using-yum-installer.html)*.  In its example

```
name=DVD for Fedora- $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=file:///media/Fedora%20$releasever%20$basearch%20DVD/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

the important thing is the pathname which you give in the `baseurl` line.  The `$releasever`, etc., are not really important.  You also have to give a *different* name in the repo file from other existing repositories.  You may also need a line at the top of the file like this:

```
[MyDVD]
```

which also has to be unique.

Check the result by doing

```
yum clean all
yum repolist
```

which should show your repository (and number of packages) with no errors.

Further reading:

- [RHEL: Add DVD to YUM repository](https://www.krenger.ch/blog/rhel-add-dvd-to-yum-repository/)
- [Using your DVD as a yum repository on a RPM based Linux](https://fritshoogland.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/using-your-dvd-as-a-yum-repository-on-a-rpm-based-linux/)